# error C2039: 'IsNearDeath': is not a member of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8 ::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, visual-studio-code

I recently upgraded my `nodejs` to `v12.3.1`, and now when I try to run `npm install` in my project repository, I am getting the preceding errors.

```
error C2059: syntax error: ')' (compiling source file ..\src\custo
m_importer_bridge.cpp) 

error C2660: 'v8::StringObject::New': function does not take 1 arg
uments (compiling source file ..\src\sass_context_wrapper.cpp)

node_modules\nan\nan_object_wrap.h(127): error C2039: 'IsNearDeath': is not a member of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v
8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>'
```

**Things I have tried**

- Deleted the node_modules folder and run `npm install`
- Closed vscode and open the solution again
- update npm to the latest

Anyone else are facing the same issue with `v12.3.1`?

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.`

Comment: Related : [ask] & [mcve]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have tried many things to solve this issue. It seems like the version `v12.3.1` is not stable yet. As a workaround, I installed the version `v10.16.0` and that fixed the issue. As I had installed the latest version previously (`v12.3.1`) the Node.js was not allowing me to install a lower version, so I had to uninstall the Node.js and install the `v10.16.0`. I hope it helps.

Update:

As @forsunnet mentioned in his comment, the issue is with the version 13.12 too, going back to version 11.x solved the issue for him.

Comment: Sibeesh, it looks like the problem has been fixed in v12.10.0 - just FYI, and for anyone else curious.

Comment: @aardvark Node version 12.12.0 did not fix it for me. Installing 10.16.3 did. I'm sticking to the LTS for now.

Comment: @aardvark getting this issue in v12.10.0

Comment: Still getting this issue with v12.13.0

Comment: Still getting the issue with v12.16.0

Comment: I'm also having same the issue after updated node to v12.16.0. Any update on this?

Comment: Same issue with version 13.12. Going back to version 11.x solved the issue for me

Answer (score 24):

I was able to fix the issue (for me at least) on Node v12.13.1:

- **delete package-lock.json**
- delete node_modules directory
- rerun npm install

Looking at the diff of package-lock.json reveals that some of the problematic packages are obviously outdated:

[image]

Comment: This also worked for me against `node 12.18.4`. Thank you!