# npm install failing saying "no member named isNearDeath"

Tags: node.js, npm

I have to say my knowledge of npm or nvm are very limited.

I currently cloned a project that I need to run.

name a `npm install` and worked fine, was able to run it with `npm run`

That was a week ago. Today I wanted to run it again and started to see multiple weird errors.

like:

```
Module build failed: Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (59)
```

which seems to be very popular, so popular that it has multiple possible answers.

it kinda "worked" the solution where I remove the package and I install one with a newer version. Taken from here (https://dev.to/letsbsocial1/node-sass-and-node-910-4ol) (plus I deleted the folders bower_components and node_modules)

Anyways, the `npm install` command is still failing, now due a weirder error.

```
                      ^
14 warnings and 9 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
```

and before of that I can see something like this:

```
In file included from ../src/binding.cpp:1:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2222:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:124:26: error: no member named 'IsNearDeath' in 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
    assert(wrap->handle_.IsNearDeath());
```

Coming from a java world these errors make no sense and I am not able to figure out what is going on.

Any of you have an idea what I can do to make it run?

I am running

```
npm 6.9.0
node v12.6.0
```

Comment: *'...I remove the package and I install one with a lower version'* - the article you linked suggested installing a newer version, not an older one. Is this a typo in your question? If not, I'd recommend trying that.

Comment: Thanks for point it out. I meant newer (but I still dont know even where to look for the versions, dont know where are declared and I cannot find them)

Comment: You can find the version history on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass?activeTab=versions). Which version did you upgrade to?

Comment: no, I mean, which version I previously had. I upgraded node-sass  to 4.7.2

Comment: According to the [README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), you need node-sass v4.12.0 (the latest version) if you want to use Node v12. Try installing that version.

Comment: That worked! I have NO idea why worked on previous days and now it stop working, how is that possible?

Comment: My guess would be that you've (intentionally or otherwise!) upgraded your Node installation since you last ran the project. Hard to tell, though! Also, if I helped fix your issue, please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`node-sass` is a 'native' module (i.e. some parts of it are implemented in a language that compiles down to machine code - in this case, C++). This means that it makes use of Node's native APIs, which can change from version to version. As such, native modules will often only work with certain versions of Node, and require updates when the version of Node changes.

`node-sass` is no exception to this rule, and their README states that if you wish to use Node v12, you must use `node-sass` v4.12.0 or higher.

Comment: Had this issue with my old project after starting to work on it again. Updating `node-sass` version from `4.11.0` to `4.12.0` really did the trick

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and it could be due to a Node upgrade: in fact I was able to solve it by downgrading from version 12 to 10, as discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56391303/4095409).